# 'Failed to connect to remote server: dial tcp ...: getsockopt: connection timed out' when initializing BOSH environment on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I followed the [documentation](https://bosh.io/docs/init-aws.html) which provide instructions to create a BOSH environment on AWS.

After setting up the necessary [AWS resources](https://bosh.io/docs/init-aws.html#prepare-aws) as defined in the documentation, when creating the BOSH environment (using bosh `create-env bosh-deployment/bosh.yml...`), I am encountering the following issue.

```
Started deploying
  Creating VM for instance 'bosh/0' from stemcell 'ami-1974417c light'... Finished (00:00:37)
  Waiting for the agent on VM 'i-00a10b77ed4c4083d' to be ready... Failed (00:08:43)
Failed deploying (00:09:20)

Stopping registry... Finished (00:00:00)
Cleaning up rendered CPI jobs... Finished (00:00:00)

Deploying:
  Creating instance 'bosh/0':
    Waiting until instance is ready:
      Starting SSH tunnel:
        Starting SSH tunnel:
          Failed to connect to remote server:
            dial tcp 10.0.0.6:22: getsockopt: connection timed out

Exit code 1
```

In my AWS account, I find the `bosh/0` VM successfully created although, it fails while waiting for the agent on the created VM.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the discussed solution for this issue under [this](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh/issues/1880) GitHub issue.